# Django: Load JSON into Bootstrap table with AJAX function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, bootstrap-4

I want to create a simple application that can discover data from a database (a live program) with `Django`. One of the features is to display the list of tables.

A response API that contains the list of table names from a database has been created:

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "results": [
        {
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "actor"
        },
        {
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "actor_info"
        },
        {
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "customer_list"
        },
        {
            "schema": "public",
            "table": "film_list"
        },
        ....
     ]
}
```

Then, I want to display the data (from API) in a bootstrap table by creating an AJAX function.
This is my **HTML** file (full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/furanzone/355b43845a29db59f1078ecbec893882)):

```
...
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-sm" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Schema</th>
    <th>Table Name</th>
   </tr></thead>
 <tbody id="divBody"></tbody>
</table>
</div>
...
```

This is my **AJAX function** (Currently, I used the GET method. I want to change into POST method later):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            BindTables();
        });

    function BindTables(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/table/",
            success: function(data){
                
                console.log("It's success");
                console.log(data.results)
                                
                var structureDiv = "";
                for (let i=0; i < data['results'].length; i++){
                    structureDiv += "<tr>" + 
                        "<td>" + data['results'][i].schema + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + data['results'][i].table + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
                }
                $("#divBody").html(structureDiv);
            }
        });
    }    
</script>
```

Currently, I can call the API and show the data into the bootstrap table when the page is loaded. However, when I click the table, the data **disappeared**. Is it normal? since I use `$(document).ready(function () {})` for this case.

I think there are some problems with the javascript function, where the data is not loaded into the table properly **(see the picture)**.

[image]

So, could you help me to fix this problem? How can I show the data from API into a bootstrap table? Any helps will be appreciated, thanks.

**Added info-1:**
[image]

Comment: everything looks ok, can you check in the dev console if there are event handlers on the table.?

Comment: @tstoev Hi, thank you for your response. I tried to check on using dev console, there is nothing on the `console` tab. I added the picture of `element` tab. I hope this picture can give you additional information.

Comment: You need to pick the handlers that are linked to libraries/components(like the one you expanded and check them one by one. It is possible that you are looking at a feature of the component. You can try bypassing it with $('divBody').closest('table').off(); This will remove all event handlers from the table.